# How to fix a gas fireplace?

Tags: gas, fireplace

We have a gas fireplace. My dad said that the pilot wouldn't stay lit, however that would mean that it needed to be cleaned. I tried to clean it and relight it. However, every time I've tried to turn it on I don't smell even a little gas like you usually would when you turn it on. What am I doing wrong? How do I check to see if there is gas?

Comment: How do you light the pilot , with a match or a push button igniter?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a picture. There may be a button you have to hold in until the pilot has been lit long enough to warm up a thermocouple, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to turn the gas valve to pilot and hold an override button to get the gas to flow. If the pilot lights wait at least 30 seconds then turn the gas valve to on. If the pilot goes out it is usually a bad thermocouple (the little metal probe sticking up that the flame hits). If this component has failed the pilot won’t stay lit ever. They are fairly inexpensive and easy to change. They are clamped at the pilot the tube goes back to the gas valve and it unscrews. They start at about $10 and that might be the problem.